# How to start QTimer in QtConcurrent::run or why QVector<QTimer*> not work

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I'm trying to create a set, timers for starting an action, for each action of a new timer with its time counter.

How to start QTimer in QtConcurrent::run or why  QVector  not work

I tried this, but writes - not the correct function call:

```
for (int i =0; i < test_checkbox.length(); i++ )
{
    if (Value == true)
    {
        if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() ==Value)
        {
               // timer->start(struc_mess_add.MS);  // work
               QtConcurrent::run(timer->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS),&timer);  // not work
         }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
        timer->stop();  
    }
}
```

But the slot on which it is tied:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(KAN_minimal()));
```

In the header file:

```
 QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
```

---

Tried to try through a vector. But it does not give an error and no work 0_o.

```
 timer = new QTimer();        // initialize the timer
 vector_qtimer.append(timer);    // put the timer in the vector

 vector_qtimer[i]->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS);
```

In the header file:

```
 QTimer *timer  = new QTimer();  
 QVector<QTimer*> vector_qtimer;
```

Comment: Your question seems very confusing. Can you put it in simple words, what are you basically trying to do and what is going wrong ? Also, Try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You make my day with this if-then-if-else mess. Why not just `if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked()) {...} else { ...stop() }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading has nothing to do with timers. QtConcurrent has nothing to do with timers, and the its implementation doesn't have an event loop, so if you try to use a timer within the code invoked by `QtConcurrent::run` - it won't work. You can, of course, schedule concurrent actions in the future:

```
// Show a message ten seconds from now, without blocking the UI
QTimer::singleShot(10000, []{ QtConcurrent::run([]{ 
  qDebug() << "The future is now.";
  QThread::sleep(2); // block to demonstrate that the UI is unaffected
  qDebug() << "Some time has passed";
}));
```

If the actions need single-shot timers, use `QTimer::singleShot` and then you don't need to manually keep track of the timers.

Otherwise, timers can be kept as values in any container that doesn't need to copy nor move them:

```
std::list<QTimer> timers;
std::array<QTimer, 10> timers;
```

You'd use `std::list` if the number of timers changes dynamically, or `std::array` if the number of them is constant.

To iterate through the list, you cannot use integer indices, but iterators - but you can still maintain an integer index to access related data:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto t = timers.begin(); t != timers.end(); ++i, ++t) {
  if (checkboxes[i]->isChecked())
    t->start();
}
```

It's also possible to add the information about the timer directly to the connection - but it's best to decouple the UI and the logic. This presumes a lot about what you want to do - it's not obvious at all that your approach is necessary or isn't too convoluted:

```
class Controller : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  int handleCount = 0;
public:
  QVariant addSomething() {
    struct 
    auto *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("ctlTimer%1").arg(handleCount));
    handleCount++;
    ...
    return QVariant::fromValue(timer);
  }
  void setEnabled(const QVariant &h, bool val) {
    auto *timer = qvariant_cast<QTimer*>(h);
    ...
  }
);

class UI : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
  QPushButton m_add{"Add"};
  std::list<QCheckBox> m_checkboxes;
public:
  UI(QWidget *parent = {}) : QWidget(parent) {
    m_layout.addWidget(&m_add);
    connect(&m_add, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &UI::add);
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void add();
  Q_SIGNAL void toggled(const QVariant &, bool);
  void addSomething(const QVariant &handle) {
    m_checkboxes.emplace_back(QStringLiteral("Checkbox %1").arg(m_checkboxes.size()+1));
    auto *cb = &m_checkboxes.back();
    layout()->addWidget(cb);
    connect(cb,  &QCheckBox::toggled, [=](bool val){ emit toggled(handle, val); });
  }
};
```

Now the `UI` and the `Controller` are decoupled, and they get composed in e.g. `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Controller ctl;
  UI ui;
  connect(&ui, &UI::add, [&]{ ui.addSomething(ctl.addSomething()); });
  connect(&ui, &UI::toggled, &ctl, &Controller::setEnabled);
  ui.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```